# HTML5 Offline storage web framework

Tags: django, gwt, html, offlineapps, pyjamas

I am looking for a web app framework which can automatically generate an HTML5 offline storage based app, so while the users become disconnected they still can view the data which normally is stored on a server

Also currently I am using Django and it would be great if there was a framework which could pull data from Django and present that as an offline app.

From the related questions suggested by stackoverflow, while writing this question, I found one interesting link mentioning that GWT has such functionality, I would like to know more about that if possible and if it can generate an HTML5 offline app

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Rather than server-side frameworks, you should be taking a look at JavaScript frameworks.

Dojo Storage will transparently select between providers such as Google Gears, Adobe AIR or plain old HTML 5 local storage. Dojo 1.5 - dojox.storage: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.5/dojox/storage

There's also jQuery local storage: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/saveit

... or jStorage, which can act as a storage plugin for jQuery, Prototype or MooTools: http://www.jstorage.info/

With any of these, you should be able to use a quick little AJAX call to pull (JSON perhaps) data from your server and use one of these tools to help minimise your storage code.

Comment: Seems to be the most appropriate solution for now, as I couldn't find a web framework which could generate a nice HTML5 offline-storage front-end for enabling the user to to temporarily modify/view his data, which would by synced upon re-connection

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about a standalone app, not a django app.
This can be done with javascript (jQuery, Sproutcore, JavascriptMVC, Pyjamas ...) or Adobe AIR, or...
Pulling data from Django is just a matter of setting up a syncing method, most probably using JSON, to fill up the browser local storage. So this is not django-specific at all.

If you want a standalone django app, this can be done if you bundle in a python desktop app django with a built-in server, that's [another question](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/)

Comment: "Hi, I am looking for a web app framework which can automatically generate an HTML5 offline storage based app" -- basically I wanted to know if there is something that would automagically generate a nice html5-storage enabled front-end from my Django app. But it seems that there is no such program that can do this.

Comment: Django pluggables app usually don't mess too much with the client side. Some, like Dajaxproject can help you with XHR requests and views, but I know none covering the local storage subject. But if you know jQuery, this is trivial, using things like http://jstorage.info

Answer (score 1):

You could suggest the users to create web apps or use google gears instead... I don't know if this will fill the question, but, i'm in the same way. However, I'm developing an governamental solution who will run only for some kind of people, so, I can have a few control about the user's environment... All you need to do is to use jquery to detect if user has a live connection, or offer to the users a 'preferences' page where you define the behavior of the page itself... 
Some info about offline cache: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html

PS.: In another post in stackoverflow, I 've found another question: [html5 offline caching with php driven sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885509/html5-offline-caching-with-php-driven-sites)... The last Post said:

> HTML5 offline caching does not work to make your pages interact; it works only to make a
>   particular page available offline. Basically, it works on a URL-by-URL basis. If you
>   absolutely need offline functionality, you will be forced to make it work in JS.
>
> Also, make sure your manifest includes all resources used by all pages.
>
> Hope this helps!

Hope it helps!!